# How to ignore NaN values from a list?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, nan

I have an Excel file with a column that consists of measurements, for example:

**Measurements**

**24235**

**325434**

**This one is empty, so it's a NaN value**

**45345**

I'm extracting that column from excel into a python list, which will result in: *list = ['24235', '325434', 'nan', '45435']*. I want to ignore NaN values to be able to calculate the total measurement. I have this to prevent taking into consideration NaN values, but it's not working:

```
if list[i] != 'nan' or list[i] != float('NaN'):
    counter += int(list[i])
```

It's entering the *if statement* even when it's false. How can I fix this?

Comment: don't know if this works in pure python, but it works in pandas' nans: try check the value against itself: ```if list[i] == list[i]: counter += int(list[i])```

Comment: Won't that always be true? @olenscki

Comment: Your solution worked @olenscki could you explain how and why that works if it's possible? I would appreciate it and thank you!

Comment: That's not the case, at least with pandas' NaNs. I have read once the explanation to this phenomena, it's said that NaN are built in a certain way that they aren't equal to themselves. Since you're working in pure python I don't know if the NaNs you're using act the same way the NaN of pandas

Comment: Oh, okay. I would've thought that NaN would be equal to NaN, but guess not. I appreciate your help, thank you very much! @olenscki

Comment: It's fine... I felt really confuse when I heard it first time too, but it also worked for me with my problem at the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the 'nan' elements like this:

```
original = ['24235', '325434', 'nan', '45435']
filtered = [int(element) for element in original if element != 'nan']
print(sum(filtered))
```

Output:

```
395104
```

Comment: I didn't try this solution, but I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**try, except  ValueError**

use try except and prevent the **if..else** old school style. this is more effecient and prevent you from writing long and complicated logic. pay attention to my comments **inline**

```
# init the counter
counter = 0    
# iterate on the list and pick list element one by one
for each in f:         
  try:
    # .. doWork() ... 
    counter += int(each)  # convert the element to int. if something wrong we will get ValueError which we will catch/except later.
  except ValueError:      # if we get valueerror exception that   means we hit nan. so we skip and continue. 
    pass   # you can use continue instead of using pass, both are valid!
```

We want to except only `ValueError` exceptions, because its raised by invalid `int()` conversion, like `int(nan)`.
for each other exception we want to raise it!

Comment: I think `continue` should be `pass` instead, and the `try-except` block should be inside the loop. Also `counter` needs to be initialised first.

Comment: you are right my bad. i will fix it. why try except inside the loop ?. no need to enter the try except inside the loop. i can enter it but it is the same, if some thing went wrong in the conversion the exception well keep tell hiting the first `try`

Comment: Well, you want the code to ignore ValueErrors and there might be many 'nan' in the list. If the block is outside the loop, execution will stop at the first 'nan'.

Comment: oh man i need coffe. thank you. i will fixit :-) i am tired

Comment: I didn't try this solution, but I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you!

Comment: @PApostol - regarding `pass` and `continue` both are valid after i post the fix.

Comment: @JaimeMiranda - go ahead and try it. if you find my answer useful please vote up and accept it (by pushing the grey V nearby). thanks.